# What is a mathematical expression for the sequence $\{1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,\dots\}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is a mathematical expression for the sequence $\{1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,\dots\}$, that is $1$ and $-1$, two at a time alternating?

Comment: Do you means the _sequence_ of $1$s and $-1$s, two at a time alternating?

Comment: Try working with powers of $-1$.  You have $-1$ to an even power is positive one, while $-1$ to an odd power is negative one.  Now, try defining the exponent in a convenient way so that it goes even, even, odd, odd, etc... perhaps a quadratic might work well.  (what does $(n^2+n)/2$ look like in terms of even and odd numbers as a sequence?)

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting with $n=0$, these all work. 
$$\begin{align}
a_n&=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\\
a_n&=(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\\
a_n&=\cos(n\pi/2)+\sin(n\pi/2)\\
a_n&=\sqrt{2}\cdot\sin\big((2n+1)\tfrac{\pi}4\big)
\end{align}$$

If I'm being honest, being able to come up with these things for me comes from having seen them before.  But in each case you can think about the pattern of even/odd exponents for $-1$ or the periodicity mod 4 if you were trying to build these having no prior knowledge.

$\color{blue}{Update}:$ And modified from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482635/some-formulae-for-a-periodic-sequence-1-1-1-1) so it starts $a_0=1$,
$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\sqrt{2}\cdot\cos\big((2n-1)\tfrac{\pi}4\big)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thank you very much.

Comment: Third is the most intuitive IMHO

Comment: @Elimination Sorry, I just reordered and may have screwed up your reference.

Comment: Now placed as second :)

Comment: I like the last one.  :)

Comment: @SimpleArt, easiest to work with (in e.g. recurrences).

Comment: @alex.Jordan: I added the cosine version from an old post to group them all together. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the sine version, its absolute vaules cannot be one. Should it maybe be $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: I took the liberty of fixing the sine version. (It was already $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ when I first saw it.)

Comment: @Tito, Matthias Good catch with $\sqrt{2}$. Tito, I think the cosine needs adjustment. The other sequences here begin indexing at $n=0$, and with indexing that begins at $n=0$, the cosine sequence you added is $\{-1,1,1,-1,-1,\ldots\}$. I think one way to adjust it is to drop the minus sign and shift the $2n+1$ to $2n-1$.

Comment: @alex.Jordan: Changes made. I should have noticed that.  :)

Comment: @alex.Jordan I've also asked a new question generalizing the phenomenon of using triangular numbers on $(-1)^n$. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059412/generalizing-1n-by-using-kth-level-figurate-numbers).

Answer (score 11):

The sequence $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=-1$, $a_3=-1$, $a_4=1$ and so on satisfies the recursion
$$
a_0=1,\quad a_1=1,\qquad a_{n+2}=-a_n
$$
so its characteristic equation is $t^2+1=0$. Thus the general solution is of the form
$$
xi^n+y(-i)^n
$$
The initial conditions tell that $x+y=1$ and $xi-yi=1$, thus
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=1\\[4px]
x-y=-i
\end{cases}
$$
that gives
$$
x=\frac{1-i}{2},\quad y=\frac{1+i}{2}
$$
Since $i=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2}$, we can write
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigl(
  (1-i)(\cos\tfrac{n\pi}{2}+i\sin\tfrac{n\pi}{2})+
  (1+i)(\cos\tfrac{n\pi}{2}-i\sin\tfrac{n\pi}{2})
\bigr)\\[6px]
&=\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}+\sin\frac{n\pi}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: +1 for showing a general approach to this class of problems

Answer (score 3):

A rather exotic formula uses ***tribonacci numbers*** $T_n$,

$$a_n = -(-1)^{T_n} = 1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,\dots$$

where,

$$T_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\tbinom{n-k}{j}\tbinom{j}{k-j}=1, 1, \color{blue}{2, 4}, 7, 13, \color{blue}{24, 44}, 81, 149, \color{blue}{274, 504},\dots$$

and we define $T_0=1$.

**P.S.** The above has period $4$. For other periods which uses the *Fibonacci numbers* etc, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2058350/4781).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply [interpolate$(1,1,-1,-1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate(1,1,-1,-1)), and then use $x=n\bmod4$:

$$a_n=\frac{2}{3}(n\bmod4)^3-5(n\bmod4)^2+\frac{31}{3}(n\bmod4)-5$$

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question as: "How can we define this sequence formally?"

A more general question is: how can we define $x = (a,a,b,b,a,a,b,b,a,a,\ldots)$ formally?

If you prefer the convention that sequences start at $0$, use:

$$x_i = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&a, && \mbox{if} \;{\left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor} \in 2\mathbb{Z}\\
&b, && \mbox{if} \;{\left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor} \in 2\mathbb{Z}+1
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

If you prefer the convention that sequences start at $1$, use:

$$x_i = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&a, && \mbox{if} \;{\left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor} \in 2\mathbb{Z}+1\\
&b, && \mbox{if} \;{\left\lfloor\frac{i}{2}\right\rfloor} \in 2\mathbb{Z}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

---

The above definitions are "set-theoretic." But we can also give an "algebraic" definition. This has the benefit that our numbering conventions become irrelevant. We begin by telling the reader that by $\sum$, we mean concatenation of sequences. Then we write: $$x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (a,a,b,b)$$

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of exponents of $-1$ (i.e. $0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,\cdots$ but also $0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3\cdots$) can follow the recurrence

$$e_{n+2}=e_n+1,\\e_0=e_1=0.$$

The general solution is given by

$$e_n=\frac n2+c_0+c_1(-1)^n$$ and you can determine the constants from the initial conditions, giving

$$e_n=\frac n2-\frac{1-(-1)^n}4.$$

The method generalizes to runs of length $k$, involving the $k^{th}$ roots of the unit.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $\{a_0,a_1,a_2, \dots \}$ with $a_n$ defined as the coefficient of the $n$th power of $x$ in the expansion of $(1+x)/(1+x^2)$ will do.