# A simple mathematical expression for the periodic sequence $2,0,1,7,8,8,2,0,1,7,8,8,2,0,1,7,8,8,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is a mathematical expression for the sequence $$2,0,1,7,8,8,2,0,1,7,8,8,2,0,1,7,8,8,...$$

Like this Following it's  not I want to answer
$$a_{n}=\begin{cases}
2&n=6k\\
0&n=6k+1\\
1&n=6k+2\\
7&n=6k+3\\
8&n=6k+4\\
8&n=6k+5
\end{cases}$$

such this:[simple expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696201/what-is-a-mathematical-expression-for-the-sequence-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-dots?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Egreg's solution to the linked problem shows a general approach you can use; you just take a combination of powers of sixth roots of unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DFT (discrete fourier transform) gives
$$a_k={13\over3}-{2\over3}(-1)^k-{11\over6}\cos{k\pi\over3}-{5\sqrt{3}\over2}\sin{k\pi\over3}+{1\over6}\cos{2k\pi\over3}-{\sqrt{3}\over6}\sin{2k\pi\over3}\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

It's also the decimal digits of $\dfrac{201788}{999999}$ after the radix point.

Answer (score 2):

A generating function could be $g(x)=\dfrac{2+x^2+7x^3+8x^4+8x^5}{1-x^6}$

so the $n$th term of the sequence is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $g(x)$, which can be found by dividing the $n$th derivative of $g(x)$ at $x=0$ by $n!$, i.e. $\dfrac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$

Comment: But How to find  $g^{(n)}(0)?$

Comment: I wouldn't bother.  You know what the sequence is, and I would be satisfied with the first line of my answer as "a mathematical expression"

Comment: You could try Wolfram Alpha and keep clicking on "more terms" to see the [series expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series+expansion+at+x%3D0+of+(2%2Bx%5E2%2B7x%5E3%2B8x%5E4%2B8x%5E5)%2F(1-x%5E6))

Answer (score 2):

You can use
$$-\frac13\left(13\cos\left(\frac\pi3n\right) + 15\cos\left(\frac\pi3\left(n-2\right)\right) + 2\cos\left(\pi n\right) + \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\left(n-1\right)\right) - 13\right).$$