# A simple mathematical expression for the periodic sequence $(1, -2, -1, 2, 1, -2, -1, 2,\dots)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

The sequence is just $S_n=1, -2, -1, 2$ repeated indefinitely. The best I can do is:

$$S_n= \frac{(i - 2)\,i^n}{2i}  + \frac{(i+2)\,(-i)^n}{2i}  $$

where $i$ is the imaginary unit. In fact, this expression is where the sequence comes from. Can it be simplified, like using $(-1)^n$ for an alternating sequence of $1$ and $-1$? These values appear as [part of a larger formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41133632/6732794). Currently, I am simply using a more computational expression: `V(n) = the (n modulo 4)'th element of [+1,-2,-1,+2]`, but this is rather hacky.

Comment: Another option is to utilize $\sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi n}{2})$ to artificially recreate the modular nature of the question

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=closed+form+1,+-2,+-1,+2,+1,+-2,+-1,+2,+...) finds something similar to you.

Comment: It's simple to prove that your Sn is the only algebraic way to get this sequence. So other methods would have to depend on other functions.

Comment: @Shifty: Here is a rather exotic formula using the _Tribonacci numbers_ $T_n$ as $$S_n = \frac{3-(-1)^n}{2}\,(-1)^{T_n}$$ with $T_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

$$\cos(\pi n/2) -2\sin(\pi n/2)$$

Comment: Nice one. :) $\text{  }$

Comment: (+1) Didn't notice your answer before I answered. I started at $n=1$, but it was the same.

Comment: This is really elegant, tidy, and fairly understandable at-a-glance given a sufficient familiarity with $cos$ and $sin$. Considering the full range of math functions, it best answers the question as stated. It is also easy to generalize to any alternation of 2 separating alternating integer sequences. That said, I probably wouldn't use this for my specific use-case, since trig functions are generally absent and would be unexpected and surprising.

Answer (score 5):

Per the OP's request, given the sequence,
$$\alpha_n=1,-2,-1,2,1,-2,-1,1,\dots$$
and $\alpha_0=1$, we are to generate it using $(-1)^n$ and well-defined sequences of integers. The unsigned version is easy to do,
$$\beta_n = \tfrac{3-(-1)^n}2=1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,\dots$$
So the problem really is to generate the signs,
$$U_n = 1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,\dots$$
and fortunately answered by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696201/what-is-a-mathematical-expression-for-the-sequence-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-dots?) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482635/some-formulae-for-a-periodic-sequence-1-1-1-1),
$$U_n =(-1)^{n(n+1)/2} = \sqrt{2}\cos\tfrac{(2n+1)\pi}4$$

> $\color{blue}{Update:}$ We also have the rather exotic,
>   $$U_n = (-1)^{T_n}$$
>   with ***tribonacci numbers*** $T_n$,
>   $$T_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k-1}\tbinom{n-k-1}{j}\tbinom{j}{k-j}=\color{blue}0,1, 1, \color{blue}{2, 4}, 7, 13, \color{blue}{24, 44}, 81, 149, \color{blue}{274, 504},\dots$$
>   and $T_0=0$.

Alternatively, we seek,
$$V_n = \tfrac{2n+1-(-1)^n}4= 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,\dots$$
which [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033953/defining-a-perplexing-two-dimensional-sequence-explicitly) has considered. It then gives us ***three*** ways to form $\alpha_n$ as,

> $$\alpha_n = \beta_n \,U_n=\tfrac{3-(-1)^n}2\,(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}\,=\,\tfrac{3-(-1)^n}2\,(-1)^{T_n}\tag1$$

and

> $$\alpha_n = \beta_n \,(-1)^{V_n} = \tfrac{3-(-1)^n}2\,(-1)^{\frac14\big(2n+1-(-1)^n\big)}\tag2$$

**P.S.** For a signed sequence with period $5$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060930/formula-for-a-periodic-sequence-of-1s-and-1s-with-period-5).

Comment: Sorry if I was misleading. I did not mean to imply that a solution _had_ to be generated using $(-1)^n$ (although, given the nature of the sequence, I would expect it to show up!). I simply meant that I seek a clear and succint mathematical way of expressing the sequence, like how $(-1)^n$ is so often used in formulas to cleanly express a pattern of alternating $1$'s and $-1$'s.

Comment: Nonetheless, excellent work! I like that you devised an expression using only integers and elementary arithmetic (no complex numbers, trig, transcendentals, conditionals, piece-wise definitions, floor/ceiling, etc.). I especially like the version using the triangular numbers $n(n+1)/2$ to produce a pattern of signs that alternate 2 at a time. That said, it's a bit too complicated and can take some time for a reader to parse what expression is doing and how it works.

Comment: @shiftydog: You're welcome. I liked the challenge of expressing the period $4$ using only integers and was glad it lead, among other things, to the tribonacci numbers, a sequence quite dear to me.  :)

Comment: @shiftydog: I've asked a question generalizing the phenomenon of using triangular numbers on $(-1)^n$. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059412/generalizing-1n-by-using-kth-level-figurate-numbers).

Answer (score 4):

This can be done easily with Discrete Fourier Transform. Observe that
$$ \operatorname{DFT}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1-2i \\ 0 \\ 1 + 2i \end{bmatrix}
$$
Using the convention
$$
\operatorname{DFT}(\mathbf{v})(\xi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} \mathit{v}_x e^{2\pi i \xi x/n}
$$
Hence the inverse DFT gives a periodic interpolation for your sequence:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1 - 2i}{2} e^{-2\pi i x/4} + \frac{1 + 2i}{2} e^{-6\pi i x/4}
$$
[image: DFT]

Comment: Great stuff! +1

Comment: This looks very interesting. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the DFT, or even just the plain FT, so this is well beyond my current comprehension :)

Answer (score 3):

Your expression can be slightly simplified if $n=2k$ we have,
$$\frac{i^{2k}}{2i}[(i-2)+(2+i)]=i^{2k}=(-1)^k.$$
If $n=2k+1$ we have, $$\frac{1}{2i}[(i-2)i^{2k+1}-(2+i)i^{2k+1}]=2(-1)^{k+1}.$$  So 
$$a_n= \begin{cases} 
      (-1)^k & n=2k \\
    \\
      2(-1)^{k+1} & n=2k+1 
   \end{cases}
,$$ where k is an integer.

Comment: I fixed a typo in your exponent.

Comment: Here is an even greater "simplification": $a_n=1$ if $n=4k$, $-2$ if $n=4k+1$, $-1$ if $n=4k+2$ and $2$ if $n=4k+3$. IOW, I fail to see how this answers the question.

Comment: How does it not answer this portion of the question, "In fact, this expression is where the sequence comes from. Can it be simplified, like using $(−1)^n$ for an alternating sequence of 11 and −1−1?"

@Did ...?

Comment: Thank you @TitoPiezasIII  !

Comment: If your question is genuine, you might wish to read the OP's first comment to @Tito's answer.

Comment: That comment did not exist when I posted this, sorry.

Comment: This is a fine answer. In fact, I upvoted it earlier along with @Wood's answer, which combines both cases into a single expression. While not as economical as other expressions, it eliminates the use of the tricky use of $i$, and is arguably clearer and more straight-forward than most of the single-expression solutions--even the accepted answer. It is a nice balance between the compactness of a single-expression and the immediate clarity of the obvious 4-cased piece-wise definition.

Comment: @shiftydog First, why should a 2-cases piecewise definition be viewed as different from a 3-cases or a 4-cases definition? Please explain. Second, everything in your question points at no-cases definitions. But now you say you were after cases definition? Please explain.

Comment: @Did Right, I definitely _prefer_ a single unconditional expression, given that it's terse, clear, and uses simple operations, but I know sometimes those qualities are often at odds with each other, so I didn't (mean to) _require_ a single-expression. I'm not against a multi-case solution in principle; such a solution simply weighs clarity and simplicity over brevity. So this answer is perfectly valid, but obviously I did not select it due to other considerations. I apologize that my question was unclear. Next time, I'll try to make the specifications less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write it using a function depending only of $(-1)^n$, because such a function takes only two values, and you need four. On the other hand a function of $i^n$ takes four values, so what you did is OK.

Comment: We can eke out more periodic values from $(-1)^n$ if $n$ is more complicated than a linear function. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059412/generalizing-1n-by-using-kth-level-figurate-numbers/).

Comment: @Tito Piezas III My answer referred strictly to the dependency on $(-1)^n$. But of course, if one is willing to allow dependencies on $(-1)^\text{something else}$, then it is possible to obtain longer periods.

Answer (score 2):

You need a period of $4$, so powers of $-1$ won't help.  As you select expressions you need to think about what the objective is.  If you just want to compute the value, your $V(n)$ is a fine expression.  It returns the value you want.  What is wrong with that?  Any other formula, like the one early in your post, is only valuable if it does something more.  Maybe it simplifies with stuff later in your application, or maybe it impresses some reader.  You could do powers of $-1$ and $-1^{n/2}$ where that is integer division, but that will be logically equivalent to what you found already.

Comment: Surprisingly, for period $6$, one can use powers of $(-1)^k$ and, of all things,  _Fibonacci numbers_ $F_n$ as $$W_n = (-1)^{n+F_{n+1}} = 1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,\dots$$ Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848384/4781). But there doesn't seem to be a well-known sequence one can use for period $4$ though.

Comment: Oh, I correct myself. It seems the [_Tribonacci numbers_](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html) $T_n$ will work, $$W_n = (-1)^{T_n} = 1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,\dots$$ and with $T_0 = 0$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII:  I would suggest that is more complicated that what we have, needing to define $F_n$.  Yes, you can use Binet's formula to get something explicit in $n$, but it is a comparative mess.

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can do this with ($n$ starting at $1$):

```
(2-n%2)*(-1)**(n//2)
```

Which doesn't require the math module.

Comment: In more general, not Python-specific terms: this formula uses only rational numbers.

Comment: @KevinReid Only integers, actually.

Comment: @Did "n//2" means integer division in Python. It gives $0$ if $n=1$. It's the same as "math.floor(n/2)", or $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$.

Comment: https://repl.it/EqZ9

Comment: OK, so no $i$ involved.

Comment: I like this, although in actual Python code, I would probably just do `(+1, -2, -1, +2)[n % 4]` for clarity. For a mathematical formula, this is a nice, compact solution, and can be made more "math-like" rather than "code-like" (as well as shifted to have $n$ starting from 0) by replacing `n%2` with Iverson brackets $[n \, even]$ and `n//2` with $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$. It is a bit opaque, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [interpolate$(1,-2,-1,2)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate(1,-2,-1,2)), and then use $x=n\bmod4$:

$$S_n=-\frac{1}{3}(n\bmod4)^3+4(n\bmod4)^2-\frac{38}{3}(n\bmod4)+10$$