# Generalizing $(-1)^{n}$ by using $k$th-level figurate numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, number-theory

One kind of [*figurate numbers*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FigurateNumber.html) are, starting with $\color{blue}{n=1}$,
$$P_1(n) = n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,\dots$$
$$P_2(n) = \tfrac{n(n+1)}{2!} = 1, 3, 6, 10, 15,\dots$$
$$P_3(n) = \tfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3!} = 1, 4, 10, 20, 35,\dots$$
$$P_4(n) = \tfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4!} =1, 5, 15, 35, 70,\dots$$
namely the linear, triangular, tetrahedral, pentatope, etc.

> Using $(-1)^n$ to generate an alternating series is well-known. But what if we replace the exponent of $(-1)^n$ with higher figurate numbers $P_k(n) $?

Thus we get the sequences,
$$\begin{aligned}
S_1(n) &=-(-1)^{P_1(n)} = \color{blue}{1,-1},1,-1,\dots\\
S_2(n) &= -(-1)^{P_2(n)}=  \color{blue}{1, 1, -1, -1}, 1, 1, -1, -1,\dots\\
S_3(n) &= -(-1)^{P_3(n)}=  \color{blue}{1, -1, -1, -1}, 1, -1, -1, -1,\dots\\
S_4(n) &= -(-1)^{P_4(n)}= \color{blue}{1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1},\dots
\end{aligned}$$

and so on. The periods $\omega_k$ for $k=1,2,3,\dots8$ are $\omega_k = 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16.$

> **Q:** How can we express the period $\omega_k$ as a function of $k$?

**P.S.** This was inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057991/a-simple-mathematical-expression-for-the-periodic-sequence-1-2-1-2-1-2/).

Comment: Does the pattern of periods continue -- $n$ copies of $2^n$?

Comment: @pjs36: I didn't check beyond $k=8$. I was getting cross-eyed looking at the signs.  :)

Comment: Exactly why I didn't check myself :P Maybe I'll write a program with [Sage](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) if I get some time, just to see.

Comment: Update: Yes, it appears that the sequence of periods is the concatenation of $n$ copies of $2^n$; it is true that $\omega_k = 2^{\lceil\log_2(k)\rceil}$ (I think that's the formula I want: it's the smallest power of $2$ that's at least $k$) for $k \le 257$ (so $\omega_{257}$ seems to be $512$ as expected). If I could figure out how to share the Sage notebook page I would. I'll leave it to someone else to *show* that this is true... unless I *really* need to put off grading finals :)

Comment: @pjs36: I guess it is this [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A062383).

Comment: The period is certainly a divisor of $2^{\lceil\log_2(k)\rceil}$. Perhaps I can return to write the proof if there is time tonight. I have no proof though that it would be exactly $2^{\lceil\log_2(k)\rceil}$. In the mean time, perhaps you can work it out yourself. You need to think about the powers of $2$ dividing $k$ consecutive numbers.

Comment: You might be interested in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336334/finding-the-periods-of-a-sequence-of-integers-reduced-mod-m

Answer (score 2):

A comment instead of an answer, but too long for the "comment"-format -

I understand things that the problem is the parity of the binomial-coefficients; that coefficients are along columns in the lower triangular Pascal matrix ***P***, so the columns, expressed by $P \pmod 2$ should give the pattern of the signs in your question.
Here is a "graphical" expression for the patterns; the columns are to be read downwards beginning at the diagonal. The "1" give the sign $(-1)^1=-1$, the dots the positions of $(-1) ^0=1$ :

```
  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  .  .  .  .  .  .
  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .  1  .  1  .  .  .  .  .
  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .  1  1  1  1  .  .  .  .
  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .  1  .  .  .
  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .  1  1  .  .
  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

The first column follows the sequence -1,-1,-1,-1,... ; th second -1,1,-1,1,... , the third -1,-1,+1,+1,... and so on and confirms the $2^k$ - blockwise length of periodicity which you have already found. Of course, this pattern is well known and has been explored in extreme broadth&width; I'll see whether I can find some well known way of proof online ...

Comment: For a proof, consider the recursive definition of the binomial coefficients, $\binom{n+1}k=\binom nk+\binom n{k-1}$, modulo $2$. Suppose for induction that the $2^n\times2^n$ block of the matrix has only $1$'s in its bottom row (the row labelled $2^n-1$). Then the recursion shows that the next row (labelled $2^n$) has two $1$'s (at positions $0$ and $2^n$) and $0$'s everywhere else, and those two $1$'s generate two copies of the original $2^n\times2^n$ block. Then these form a $2^{n+1}\times2^{n+1}$ block with only $1$'s in its bottom row, completing the induction.

Comment: Notice the [Sierpiński triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle)